# LST MODIS harmonic fitting in Google Earth Engine - Predicting Future Scenarios?

Tags: modis, google-earth-engine

I've been working on code for harmonic fitting of MODIS LST data. The code is working fine; however I would like to create future LST images in future dates by using the "fitting" band. Thus, I would like to know if is it possible to create predicted temperature images by using the fitted collection?

Code: [Link to access the base code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b4611b3a1adb542265062fd1d4c62d3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like this at the end of your code:

```
var futureDateImage = ee.Image(ee.Date('2018-12-31')
      .difference('2000-01-01', 'year')
      .multiply(2 * Math.PI));
var sin = futureDateImage.sin();
var cos = futureDateImage.cos();

var extrapolated = ee.Image.cat([
  ee.Image(1), futureDateImage, cos, sin
]).multiply(harmonicTrendCoefficients)
  .reduce('sum')
  .rename('extrapolated')
  .clip(polygon);
Map.addLayer(extrapolated, {min: 0, max: 35}, 'extrapolated');
```